# Is there priority for TLS alert?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

For example, a client hello is malformed and cannot be parsed. At the same time, the protocol version in it is not supported by the server. In this case, should the server respond with decode error alert or protocol version alert? Does it depend on the implementation or is there a requirement on the priorities of the alerts?

Comment: How would the server know what the protocol being attempted is if the very first message doesn't conform to the expected format?

Comment: For example, the malformed part is cipher_suite_length value being very large. The server can parse the protocol version and know that it doesn't support that version (protocol_version alert). It can also parse the remaining parts to know there's a malformed length field (decode_error alert)